# Saving the "filters" tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-naming

Since there's no reputation reward or stack-exchange virtual stickers for it, I'm using this space to say thanks to @scottbb for valiant effort to save the [filters](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filters) tag, by making it refer to actual, real-world filters rather than digital post-processing filters. This is a bit quixotic, but, hey — it does make the thing a bit more useful than having it as a mess of "effect" and physical filter questions mixed together.

People are still gonna keep coming by and using it for Instagram questions (or, you know, "What filter do I need to take pictures like I saw in National Geographic?" — *sigh*), though, so we will need to either keep a constant eye on it, or come up with some non-ambiguous synonym and use that instead. I don't have any ideas though, so... opening discussion. :)

Comment: upvoted. *obviously* =)

Answer (score 1):

First pitch: either [app-filters](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/app-filters) or [software-filters](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-filters).

I like `[app-filters]` because it's shorter, and frankly, 95% of the people who will be asking this will be about apps like Instagram, followed by Facebook, Photos, and a smattering of VSCO and others.

The pro for `[software-filters]` is that it also applies to desktop software "filters" (I don't know about others, but to me, "apps" means smartphone/tablet software. Maybe I'm a curmudgeon).

Agreed, this will be a constant PITA, however, because new users will always be coming in with "what filter did so-and-so use in this picture?" *arggh*.

Comment: More inclined to _[digital-filters]_ to be honest.

Comment: The others could be a tag synonym in that event. Still requires some diligence on our part, but it's a start.

Comment: JoanneC: `[digital-filters]` is pretty good. I'm personally just *slightly* adverse to it because I come from a digital signal processing background, where "digital filtering" goes hand-in-hand with Z-transforms. But I'd happily give up that ground if it means protecting `[filters]` for the physical ones. =)

Comment: The problem I have is that people are _still_ going to use "filters" for software effects, and we'll have to retag. Maybe that just can't be helped.

Comment: @mattdm Yep. That's the conclusion I came to awhile ago. There's really only 2 options: sweep-up duty; or giving up the tag to the "what's this effect called" Instagram crowd, and retreating to something like `[physical-filters]`. I *really* don't like the 2nd option.